# How to increment count when start activity on button click in Android?

Tags: android

I have two activities.  Whenever I go from the 1st activity to the 2nd activity count should be incremented on button click.

Here is the code in the 1st activity code for starting the 2nd activity:

```
imgCreatePost.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imgCreatePost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(1st.this, 2nd.class);
                    //finish();
                    startActivity(i);

                }
            });
```

Here is where the count is incremented `onCreate()` in the 2nd activity:

```
  visitCount = 0;
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_post);
        int increament = visitCount +=1;
        Log.e(" increament ", " = " + increament);

       if (visitCount == 10) {
            visitCount = 0;
          }}

  imgBackButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(2nd.this , 1st.class);
                //finish();
                //startActivityForResult(i, 9);
                startActivity(i);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.back, R.anim.back_out);

            }
        });
```

Whenever I come to the 2nd activity from the 1st activity increment is always 1. Why doesn't it increment one by one?

Comment: Make visitCount a static variable. A new instance is getting initialized with each new activity OR possibly pass the visitCount to the next activity as an extra with the intent from activity 1 and retrieve it in activity 2 depending on your need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static visitCount = 0;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_post);
    //int increament = visitCount +=1;
    visitCount++;
    Log.e(" increament ", " = " + increament);

   if (visitCount == 10) {
        visitCount = 0;
      }}

imgBackButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(2nd.this , 1st.class);
            //finish();
            //startActivityForResult(i, 9);
            startActivity(i);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.back, R.anim.back_out);

        }
    });
```

Comment: If we have many activity, then what we use "static" or "shared pref" ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to store "count" in SharedPreferences. This way, your "count" will persist event if the app gets restarted.

In the 2nd Activity onCreate() method, add:

```
//Retrieve last visit count from shared preferences
SharedPreferences prefs= getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); 
int visitCount = prefs.getInt("VISIT_COUNT", 0);
visitCount++;

if(visitCount == 10){
    visitCount = 0;
}


//Store visit count in SharedPreferences
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putInt("VISIT_COUNT",visitCount);
editor.apply();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make static variable for counting that can be you can count increment. See below code may help you

```
   static visitCount ;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_post);

     if(visitCount == 0){
        visit=0;
     }else{
       int increament = visitCount +=1;
       Log.e(" increament ", " = " + increament);
     }



   if (visitCount == 10) {
        visitCount = 0;
      }}

     imgBackButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(2nd.this , 1st.class);
            //finish();
            //startActivityForResult(i, 9);
            startActivity(i);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.back, R.anim.back_out);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

for That you have to take `static` variable `visitCount`  in first activity. and in `onCreate()` of second activity you have to increment counter `visitCount`.